# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSource1'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, rdlc

The following code is working well to show a rdlc report perfectly. But problem is 
there is an error after load the page first time **A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'StudentTranscript'** while the data source name is correct.

```
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<rStudentTranscript> list = StudentManager.GetStudentTrancriptById(studentId);        
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("StudentTranscript", list);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);                                  
    }       
}
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```